# Solve $7\sqrt{x-8}-\sqrt{21x+12}=2\sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $7\sqrt{x-8}-\sqrt{21x+12}=2\sqrt{3}$

$\Rightarrow 7\sqrt{x-8}-\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{7x+4}=2\sqrt{3} \tag{1}$

$\Rightarrow 7\sqrt{x-8}=\sqrt{3}\cdot(2+\sqrt{7x+4}) \tag{2}$

$\Rightarrow [7\sqrt{x-8}]^2=[\sqrt{3}\cdot(2+\sqrt{7x+4})]^2 \tag{3}$

$\Rightarrow 49\cdot(x-8)=3\cdot[4+(7x+4)+4\sqrt{7x+4}] \tag{4}$

$\Rightarrow 49x-392=21x+24+12\sqrt{7x+4} \tag{5}$

$\Rightarrow 28x-416=12\sqrt{7x+4} \tag{6}$

$\Rightarrow (28x-416)^2=(12\sqrt{7x+4})^2 \tag{7}$

$\Rightarrow 784x^2+173056-23296x=144(7x+4) \tag{8}$

$\Rightarrow 784x^2-24304x+173056=0 \tag{9}$

$\Rightarrow 49x^2-1519x+10816=0 \tag{10}$

$x=\dfrac{1519 \pm \sqrt{(-1519)^2-4\cdot49\cdot10816}}{98}=\dfrac{1519 \pm \sqrt{187425}}{98} \tag{11}$

But the answer is given as $x=20, 11$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In passing from (8) to (9).

Comment: From (8) to (9), you forget to subtract 144*4 from the left side.

Comment: The answer is wrong, when $x = 11$, the LHS is $-2 \sqrt{3}$ but not $2 \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: That's so weird. Solving the quadratic gives $x=20,11$ but like you said $x=11$ gives $-2\sqrt{3}$. How is this possible?

Comment: $11$ could be an [extraneous solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raising to the second power twice leads to large numbers. We can avoid that, so the possibility of making a mistake is smaller.

Substitute $\sqrt{3} \,t=\sqrt{x-8}\ge 0.$ Then $x=3t^2+8.$ The equation takes the form
$$7\sqrt{3}\,t-2\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{3}\sqrt{21\,t^2+60} $$  Dividing by $\sqrt{3}$ and raising to the second power gives
$$49\,t^2-28\,t+4=21\,t^2+60$$ Thus
$$28\,t^2-28\,t -56=0$$ We divide by $28$ to get
$$t^2-t-2=0$$ We are after the positive root, which is equal $t=2.$ Thus $x=3\,t^2+8=20.$

Comment: +1 for a method that doesn't require us to manually work out which of two apparent solutions is extraneous.

Comment: This is incredible. But at best I would set $t=\sqrt{x-8}$. I would never be able to know from the first step to write down $\sqrt{3}t=\sqrt{x-8}$. How did you know to do this besides natural mathematical talent? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Introducing $\sqrt{3}$ was natural as two out od three terms had that coefficient for pulling out.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that from $(8)$ to $(9)$ You completely lost $4\times144$
So It should've been
$$
784x^2 + 12480-24304x=0
$$
Also maybe you made an error while copying the problem? Because $$7\sqrt{11-8}-\sqrt{231+12}\neq 2\sqrt{3}$$
$$7\sqrt{3}-9\sqrt{3}\neq 2\sqrt{3}$$
But as @PinkRabbit pointed out $-2\sqrt{3}\neq 2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: That's so strange. Solving the quadratic formula gives $x=20, 11$ but as you said plugging in $x=11$ doesn't work. How is this possible? The problem is written as is.

Comment: Typo most likely then @ronaldchristenkkson

Comment: Since $11$ is a root of the quadratic, it is likely that the source forgot to check the roots to avoid the extraneous solution.

Comment: @ronaldchristenkkson "How is this possible" : consider the equation $~\displaystyle x = \sqrt{4} \implies x^2 = 4.~$ The equation $~x^2 = 4~$ has the two solutions $~x = 2~$ and $~x = -2.~$  However, $~x = -2~$ is not a solution to the equation $~\displaystyle x = \sqrt{4}.$